# Which version has better visual alignment and why?

Tags: shapes, page-layout, critique, alignment

I added two screenshots below and need direction on which one looks better.

[image: Version 1]
[image]

Comment: Voted to close because it's merely a "poll".

Comment: I would remove the period from the heading and make sure the lines of the bullet list are aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one, because your reasoning is correct to add more space on the left margin and align to the center of the hexagon in the logo. That's probably what you already knew, since this was posted as the first image.

Also:

- that white diamond shape under the logo should not be too strong, you don't want that shape to attract too much attention away from the logo. remove or make it smaller
- the main title "Steigen Sie.." can be shifted a bit down, to better separate between white and orange boxes and keep the text area compact
- too much blank space on the right. consider larger fonts and text lines extended

[image]

Comment: I agree with all your points, except the changing the angle of the little white shape. In the original, it matches the angle of the underside of the logo, which is an awesome detail.

Comment: Yeah, i though about that. I adjusted the image a bit, but definitely needs to be a bit smaller (in my opinion).

Comment: I agree! Better, now :)

Comment: At first, thanks for the feedback. Personally I prefer the second one, because I think the shape unter the logo is unnecessary and the logo already establishes a strong line on the left for the reader to follow down.

Comment: @DominicSternitzke Actually it doesn't -- or rather, the strong line is the centre, vertical line, not the left edge. Also, any alignment connection between the logo and the text in #2 is lost because the header is just a header, The diamond cutout in #1 helps link them together (but it does need to be smaller). Definitely go for #1.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Why is the strong line in the center? And why is the connection lost because of the separation of the areas?

Comment: The strong line is in the centre because that's the front edge of the cube, or the arrow pointing downwards in the middle. A flat horizontal line is a strong divider. The  line from the centre of the logo might go through it if you justified the text on it; but otherwise there's nothing.

Answer (score 0):

i like the first one. The spacing in left makes it stand out and easy to read. The right side is empty. Consider expanding the text or add a visual element there.